# How to combine multiple variable descriptive stats in one table in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I have this code

```r
data_2012 %>%
  group_by(job2) %>%
  filter(!is.na(job2)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(persinc2, na.rm = T),
            sd = sd(persinc2, na.rm = T))
```

Which gives me a little table for that specific variable which is perfect, however i have multiple variables that i want the mean and SD for but it all to be in the one table, how do i do that?

I am very new to R.

Comment: You may want to use a package. There are many functions that can summarize a whole dataset in one line. `dplyr::glimpse()` is one. `qwraps2` might also be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/summary-statistics.html. And there's a nice article here: https://thatdatatho.com/easily-create-descriptive-summary-statistic-tables-r-studio/

Comment: Hi! Does the reply answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `across` and have to choose your columns using the [`tidy_select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) format:

```r
data_2012 %>%
  group_by(job2) %>%
  filter(!is.na(job2)) %>%
  summarise(across(your_columns, list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                              sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

With a toy dataset

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                   sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  Species    Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Length_sd Sepal.Width_mean Sepal.Width_sd
  <fct>                  <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01           0.352             3.43          0.379
2 versicolor              5.94           0.516             2.77          0.314
3 virginica               6.59           0.636             2.97          0.322
# ... with 4 more variables: Petal.Length_mean <dbl>, Petal.Length_sd <dbl>,
#   Petal.Width_mean <dbl>, Petal.Width_sd <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

With **base R**, we may use `split()` to split the data by some factor variable. This returns a list of a number of elements that is equal to the number of levels of that factor variable. We can then obtain the `mean` and `sd` (or any other statistic you like) per column per level using members of the `*apply()` family as follows:

```
# toy data
df <- mtcars[, 1:5]

# splitting by a factor variable
lapply(split(df, df$cyl), function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(i) data.frame(Mean=mean(i), SD=sd(i)))
})
```

**Output**

```
$`4`
     mpg      cyl disp     hp       drat     
Mean 26.66364 4   105.1364 82.63636 4.070909 
SD   4.509828 0   26.87159 20.93453 0.3654711

$`6`
     mpg      cyl disp     hp       drat     
Mean 19.74286 6   183.3143 122.2857 3.585714 
SD   1.453567 0   41.56246 24.26049 0.4760552

$`8`
     mpg      cyl disp     hp       drat     
Mean 15.1     8   353.1    209.2143 3.229286 
SD   2.560048 0   67.77132 50.97689 0.3723618
```